# Delete rows with duplicated/repeated data in specified columns

Tags: mysql, field, records

I need To Delete Repeated Records (only if cod1 and Model are repeated) And Save only one of thats.

```
ID Cod1 Model
1   332  mdl1
2   332  mdl1
3   332  mdl2
4   450  mdl2
5   450  mdl2
```

The output must Be

```
ID  Cod1  Model
1    332  mdl1
3    332  mdl2
4    450  mdl2
```

Really Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this one. Replace occurrences of `Table1` with your actual table name.

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN
(SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT T2.Id
    FROM Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table1 T2 
    ON T1.Cod1 = T2.Cod1 AND T1.Model = T2.Model
    WHERE T2.ID > T1.ID
    )T
);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa1d1/1)

In the inner most query, T1 will find matching T2 records when Cod1 and Model match and T2.Id will be the larger id. So it returns IDs of rows to be deleted.  But Mysql doesn't allow you to delete from a query that is from the same table so we have to wrap that inside another SELECT statement to trick Mysql into letting you do it.  And that's it.

Comment: Excelent Idea and Example, Works Perfectly. Really Thanks.